# Enabling wireless hardware switch

Tags: wireless

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on a Compaq Presario CQ57 and I need to enable my wireless hardware switch to use it. I have a wireless key (F12) which shows a light when the switch is active (it is now red). How would I go about enabling in Ubuntu? I've tried pressing F12 normally and with Fn, none work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a common problem with that model.

Here is solution

http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-ppas/ralink-wireless/

---

Linked question :

[Wireless not recognised on a Compaq Presario CQ57](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95063/wireless-not-recognised-on-a-compaq-presario-cq57)

Comment: I received an error on the second command saying no such package.

Comment: I have found out that pressing F12 does switch the switch, but wireless is disabled anyway. Am I missing a driver?

Comment: There is a step missing in that instruction.Run `sudo apt-get update` after adding ppa

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Okay, I have fully solved the hardware switch problem. But it is still displaying that it is disabled.

Comment: is it connecting after enabling from network manager? Now what is the problem?

Comment: I can not enable it from the network manager.

Comment: run `rfkill list` and post result

Comment: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: try with `rfkill unblock wi-fi`. Though I am not sure as wireless lan still showing hard block. Did you black listed modules as told in that tutorial.

Comment: >Bogus unblock argument 'wi-fi'.

This error is thrown.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3035/discussion-between-web-e-and-harris6310)

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1413379#p1413379

Try to unload the wmi module.

For example, this worked for me on HP Mini 100e:

```
sudo rmmod hp-wmi    
sudo rmmod wmi
```

after which I could immediately connect to wi-fi.

(Find your corresponding module using lsmod)

If this works for you, you might want to blacklist the wmi module from /etc/modprobe.d/ -- see link for instructions.